# getting the name or number of the core doing the work

Tags: unix, parallel-processing

Is there a way to use the unix command line to get the name (or number) of the core that is generating or processing the work?

The purpose is check that a parallel system is actually using all cores and so i want it to return the core name as well as the ip address...

i know the IP address is

```
ifconfig
```

I jut need one for cores

This is for both OS X and Linux systems

Comment: you can check that all cores are being used by running `top`. It will list each process, (sorted by CPU descending), and it's utilization. You should see that all of your processes group near the top, and are running at near 100% each. This of course assumes that processing being performed is not I/O bound. If this is more than a one off,  your time will probably be better spent finding, and installing an appropriate monitoring tool. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sysctl` for MacOSX, and `/proc/cpuinfo` for Linux.

On Linux (RHEL/CentOS), to get number of logical cores, which is different from physical ones when hyperthreading is enabled, count number of siblings up for each physical CPUs.

```
OSTYPE=`uname`

case $OSTYPE in
  Darwin)
    NCORES=`sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu`
    NLCORES=`sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu`
    ;;
  Linux)
    NCORES=`grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l`
    NLCORES=`
      grep 'physical id\|siblings' /proc/cpuinfo |
      sed 'N;s/\n/ /' |
      uniq |
      awk -F: '{count += $3} END {print count}'
    `
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unsupported OS" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

echo "Number of cores: $NCORES"
echo "Number of logical cores (HT): $NLCORES"
```

Tested only on OS X Mountain Lion and CentOS 5. Some fixes may be needed for other systems. Note that this script is **not fully tested**. Be careful when you use it.